# not able to download images from azure server using java code

Tags: java, azure

I have uploaded images successfully in Azure server via java code but I am getting an exception when I try to download images.

Code to download:

```
try
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

   // Create the blob client.
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

   // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
   CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("mycontainer");

   // Loop through each blob item in the container.
   for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
       // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory.
       if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
           // Download the item and save it to a file with the same name.
            CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
            blob.download(new FileOutputStream("C:\\mydownloads\\" + blob.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Getting below exception,

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
    at com.test.BlobBasics.main(BlobBasics.java:106)
Caused by: com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.StorageException: The server encountered an unknown failure: OK
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:187)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:251)
    at 
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(XMLReaderImpl.java:563)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.ListBlobsResponse.parseResponse(ListBlobsResponse.java:118)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer$6.postProcessResponse(CloudBlobContainer.java:1227)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer$6.postProcessResponse(CloudBlobContainer.java:1190)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:185)
    ... 2 more
```

[Microsoft description of how to use blob storage in Java](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/)

Comment: Which version of Java SDK are you using? There has been some changes in the REST API where the XML structure has changed. Wanted to make sure that you're not using an older version of SDK to fetch the blobs list.

Comment: I am using jdk 1.7 version and downloaded latest version of jar :microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.7.0(earlier i have used 0.5.0 version) right now i was able to downloaded from Azure server via java code as expected. Thanks so  much to  icedtrees and everyone valuable solution.....

Answer (score 0):

hey use below code it will help you..

```
public void downloadAttachment() {
    try {

        final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" + "AccountName=your account name;" + "AccountKey=your account key";

        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        // Get a reference to a container.
        // The container name must be lower case
        container = blobClient.getContainerReference("container name");
        if (container.listBlobs() != null) {
            Log.d("in if ", "list conatin value");
            new downloadingAttachment().execute();
        } else {
            Log.d("in else ", "list does not any contain value ");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public class downloadingAttachment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.d("in if ", "container.listBlobs();" + container.listBlobs());
        Iterable<ListBlobItem> valuesofConatainer = container.listBlobs();
        Log.d("in if ", "valuesofConatainer=" + valuesofConatainer);

        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
            // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory.

            if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
                // Download the item and save it to a file with the same name.
                CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
                try {
                    blob.download(new FileOutputStream("your storage location" + blob.getName() + ".jpeg"));
                    Log.d(" blob.getName()=", " " + blob.getName());
                    break;

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (StorageException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```